# Get selected item on expanderView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, onclicklistener, expander

I'm using a ExpanderView to display some data in my app. But I'm having some difficulty trying to find out how to get an ExpanderViewItem's data after it's been selected.

On a ListBox you can call SelectionChanged="yourFunction" in your xaml code.. but for the expanderview I have no idea how to do this?

This is my XAML code for the expander:

```
 <!--Custom header template-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="28" />            
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Custom expander template-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomExpanderTemplate">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Width="400" Height="60" Fill="#FFF1F1F1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding procedureName}" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF00457C" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />

        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Custom expander items template-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderViewItems" >

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="15" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding flagIcon}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding N}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding RNG}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>                
            <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding ValueAndUnit}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding COM}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Line StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#C4C6CC" Stretch="Fill" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

<!--Listbox Containing ExpanderViews-->
            <ListBox Name="testsList" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <!--ExpanderView-->
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="{Binding}"                                                   
                                              HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                                              Expander="{Binding}"
                                              ExpanderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomExpanderTemplate}"
                                              x:Name="expander" 
                                              FontSize="36" 
                                              Foreground="#FF00457C" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding testItems}"
                                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderViewItems}" >                          
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I'd really appreciate any help in the right direction! This seems to be a question that is not easily answered around the web.

Answer (score 2):

@Frederik I've implemented what you've done in the code above using the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox - it still works fine for me.
I've been banging my head against the wall for a bit, but finally managed to solve it. First of all for the ItemTemplate I've made sure that the template is placed in a ListBoxItem element as it follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderViewItems" >
<ListBoxItem DataContext="{Binding}" Tap="ListBoxItem_Tap_1">
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding flagIcon}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding N}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding RNG}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>                
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding ValueAndUnit}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding COM}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Line StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#C4C6CC" Stretch="Fill" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

Once this is in place, go in the code behind and in the Tap event declared for the ListBoxItem use something like this:

```
ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;
ExpanderItemModel model = item.DataContext as ExpanderItemModel;
```

Of course, ExpanderItemModel will be whatever you're using for your expander items...

This worked fine for me

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "tap" event on the listbox:

In your XAML file add a tap event listner:

```
<!--Listbox Containing ExpanderViews-->
        <ListBox Name="testsList" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Tap="testsList_Tap" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!--ExpanderView-->
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="{Binding}"
                    ...
```

In your code behind file, implement the tap handler:

```
    private void testsList_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        someModel selectedItem = (someModel)this.testsList.SelectedItem;
        // Do something with your seleted data
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selected values by listbox selectionchanged or expanderview expanded events.
 For listbox :

```
    private void lstExams_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Model.ExamTitles data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Model.ExamTitles;
           }
     }
```

Here ExamTitles is a class which contains collections

For expanderview Expanded

```
    private void ExpanderView_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExpanderView expview = (sender as ExpanderView);
        Model.ExamTitles data = expview.Header as Model.ExamTitles;
    }
```

Hope this helps!